# The correct way to put the id/class in HTML using foreach to get the exact value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've successfully displays the data using for each here is the code:

```
<?php 
  foreach($jawapan as $row_jawapan):
?>
  <li class="vote-li" >
    <div class="round-button-circle">
      <span></span>
      <h1><?php echo $row_jawapan->answer_text;?></h1>
      <input class="id_answer" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_jawapan->id_option;?>">
      <input class="answer_text" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_jawapan->answer_text;?>">
    </div>
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now I want to get the exact value when user click on it using this code:

```
$('.vote-li').on('click', function(){
  var id_question = $('.id_question').val(),
      answer_text = $('.answer_text').val(),
      user_id = $('.user_id').val(),
      id_option = $(this).prop('id');

  var data = {
    id_question: id_question,
    user_id: user_id,
    id_option: id_option,
    answer_text: answer_text
  };
  console.log(data);
});
```

Now every time user click on the `vote-li` class the `console.log` only display the first index item even the item value is different. I think I made mistake in written the `class/id` in the `input` element, but I don't know how to put the correct id/class so that my jQuery can extract the correct data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `$('.id_question')`, `$('.answer_text').val()` and `$('.user_id')` use `$(this).find('.id_question')`, `$(this).find('.answer_text')` and `$(this).find('.user_id')`, so it will be limited only to current `.vote-li`.

Corrected code:

```
$('.vote-li').on('click', function(){
  var id_question = $(this).find('.id_question').val(),
      answer_text = $(this).find('.answer_text').val(),
      user_id = $(this).find('.user_id').val(),
      id_option = $(this).prop('id');

  var data = {
    id_question: id_question,
    user_id: user_id,
    id_option: id_option,
    answer_text: answer_text
  };

  console.log(data);
});
```